# Javascript Image Resize Calculation

Tags: javascript, math, scale, image-resizing, percentage

Let's say I have an image that is 1920 x 1280.

I'm using a slider to scale down the image, which goes from 100% to 0%, where 100% is the original size and 0% is the minimum size.

The image can be no smaller than 350 in either height, or width, so 0% should equate to this minimum size.

What formula would I use to calculate the new dimensions? If you could explain the logic, that would be helpful.

I'm certain this is an SAT question that I failed...

Comment: Is the image guaranteed to be 1920 x 1280?  Or could it be of any dimensions?

Comment: If you set 0% as 350 then just find the difference of your desired value and 350. i.e. 40% of 1920px would be (1920-350)*0.4 = `628px`

Comment: Are you happy with [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35517383/5583289)? Does it need elaboration? :)

Comment: Have you taken a look at the answer I provided? It's pretty universal and should handle what you're looking for in multiple situations.

Comment: Is [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35517383/5583289) good? Anything missing? If you're happy with it, I would appreciate it if you could accept it :). Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var min=Math.min(width,height);
var result=Math.max(min * (percentage/100),350);
var newHeight=(result/min) * height;
var newWidth=(result/min) * width;
```

Percentage between 0 and 1 (can be altered to be 0 - 100 integers instead of 0 to 1 floats). Other words are describing themselves. Maybe useful as a function:

```
function ff(height,width,percentage){    
    var min=Math.min(width,height);
    var result=Math.max(min*(percentage/100),350);
    var newHeight=(result/min) * height;
    var newWidth=(result/min) * width; 
    return [newWidth,newHeight]; 
 }
```

No math is needed for this. Css is already capable of these things.

```
min-width: 350px;
min-height:350px;
width: x% (or height: ... x%)
in a 1920 by 1280 sized div.
```

Comment: "No math is needed for this. Css is already capable of these things." – but what if HWD isn't using HTML or CSS?

Comment: Than that whatever engine it is, needs a math pack.

Comment: This seems to make 0% the original size, but I'd like 100% to represent the image's original size. The goal is to scale down from the original instead of up.

Comment: I see, the percentage was expecting a decimal value. For my purposes, I've had it converted in the calculation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The method below will re-size an image with a percentage, `0%` being a minimum value, and the image keeping aspect ratio:

The best approach would be to create a `function`, which takes the values `x`, `y`, `percentage` and `minimum`. Next, create a variable called `ratio` which is `y`/`x` (explained below). Then multiply `x` (minus `minimum`, to decrease the range, and therefore make `0%` equal `350`) by `(percentage/100)` and `y` (minus `minimum` times `ratio`, to create a different range for `y`, and therefore maintain aspect ratio) by `(percentage/100)`, and return an `array` with the re-sized `x` and `y`, each plus `minimum` (and `y` plus `minimum` times `ratio` to compensate for what we did) so `0%` is `350` and `233.333`, while `100%` is `1920` and `1280`. If the height is larger than the width, the ratio will be `y`/`x` instad of `x`/`y`, and `minimum` will be multiplied by `ratio` for `x`, instead of `y`. Have a look at this code:

```
resizeImage = function(x,y,percentage,minimum) {
    if (x > y) {
        ratio = y/x;
        rx = (x-minimum)*(percentage/100);
        ry = (y-minimum*ratio)*(percentage/100);
        return [rx+minimum,ry+minimum*ratio];
    } else {
        ratio = x/y;
        rx = (x-minimum*ratio)*(percentage/100);
        ry = (y-minimum)*(percentage/100);
        return [rx+minimum*ratio,ry+minimum];
    }
}
```

– and run it like this:

```
resizeImage(1920,1280,0,350);
// returns [350, 233.333]
resizeImage(1920,1280,30,350);
// returns [821, 547.333]
```

Have a look at this working example, using `HTML`, `JavaScript` and `jQuery` (drag the slider above the image to re-size it):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var w = 518;
    var h = 387;
    var min = 350;

    resizeImage = function(x,y,percentage,minimum) {
        if (x > y) {
            ratio = y/x;
            rx = (x-minimum)*(percentage/100);
            ry = (y-minimum*ratio)*(percentage/100);
            return [rx+minimum,ry+minimum*ratio];
        } else {
            ratio = x/y;
            rx = (x-minimum*ratio)*(percentage/100);
            ry = (y-minimum)*(percentage/100);
            return [rx+minimum*ratio,ry+minimum];
        }
    }

    $("#slider").change(function() {
        p = $("#slider").val();
        $("img").css({width:resizeImage(w,h,p,min)[0],height:resizeImage(w,h,p,min)[1]});
    })
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" step="1" id="slider" style="width:500;">
<br>
<img src="https://avatarfiles.alphacoders.com/157/157316.jpg">
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I really like this answer -- but what if I need to maintain the aspect ratio?

Comment: @HWD 1. Aspect ratio is now maintained. 2. A runnable code snippet has been added. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: This is really close, except for that neither the width, nor the height can be less than 350. So for example, a landscape would have minimum height of 350, and a portrait image would have a minimum width of 350.

Comment: @HWD, is that better? :)

Comment: Still having some problems. Say my percentage is 100% -- the image size should be its original 1920x1280, but it returns much larger dimensions.

Comment: doesn't this method resize to less than 350 ? the first example returns 233.333 for the smallest side. What if you need to resize an image to no less than 350?

Answer (score 0):

ok. to calculate the image resizing you can use the following calculation:
Max width: 1920
Max height: 1280

width Min: ?
height Min: 350

1280 - 350 = 930
930/100 = 9.3
1% equals 9.3px

1920 - 1280 = 640
350 + 640 = 990

new minimum width = 990

1920 - 990 = 930
930/100 = 9.3

1% equal to 9.3

then you will have to use the 9.3 pixel value for every 1%

if you consider that 350 pixel are the minimum values for both dimensions, your image will look strange

Answer (score 0):

After some tweaking and looking through the provided answers, here's some working code that will adjust for differences in height, width, and aspect ratios. With use of some `data` attributes, this is a good start to feed from, and if you are using a different form of communicating the data, just replace variables as needed. First, the `HTML`:

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" step="1" id="slider" style="width: 500px;" />
<div id="per">100%</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x1280" alt="My image" id="my-img" />
</div>
```

Simple enough, and when testing, change the `src` attribute of the `img` tag to see how the code handles different sizes. Now the fun part:

```
var id = function(i){return(document.getElementById(i));},
    slider = id('slider'),
    per = id('per'),
    img = id('my-img'),
    d_w = 0,
    d_h = 0,
    min = 350,
    reSize = function(percent) {
        var h = slider.getAttribute('data-h') == 'true',
            s_h = (parseFloat(slider.getAttribute('data-step-h')) * percent) + min,
            s_w = (parseFloat(slider.getAttribute('data-step-w')) * percent) + min,
            o_h = (d_h / d_w) * s_w,
            o_w = (d_w / d_h) * s_h;
        img.style.height = ((h) ? s_h : o_h).toString() + 'px';
        img.style.width = ((h) ? o_w : s_w).toString() + 'px';
    };
img.addEventListener('load', function() {
    d_w = this.width;
    d_h = this.height;
    slider.setAttribute('data-h', (d_w > d_h));
    slider.setAttribute('data-step-h', (d_h - min) / 100);
    slider.setAttribute('data-step-w', (d_w - min) / 100);
    slider.addEventListener('input', function() {
        var perc = parseFloat(this.value);
        per.innerHTML = perc.toString() + '%';
        reSize(perc);
    }, false);
}, false);
```

Few quick pointers, make sure to wrap this in an `onload` or better yet, `DomContentLoaded` method like:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()( /* Code */ }, false);
```

And keep in mind the `range` type of `input` isn't supported in older IE, some maybe some `hidden` inputs instead? Also, instead of `input` in the `slider` event, it has to be `change` in IE 10 so keep that in mind for cross browser-ness.

Breakdown of the code, yeah? Alright, first we declare some variables, where `id` is just to grab by ID, grab the elements, have some more 'global' like variables (`d_w`, `d_h`, and `min`) where `d_w` is `default width` and `d_h` is, yep, `default height`. The `reSize()` function grabs the data assigned to the image and uses it for calculations and determining which side is longer, followed by `s_h` and `s_w` which uses the step to adjust the pixels, some aspect ratio equations, and finally hit the `width` and `height` of the element with CSS.

`slider.addEventListener` does a few simple things, like update the percent and run the `reSize()` function when it moves. Again, make sure to check for IE 10 and replace `input` with `change` if you want this to work on that... 'browser'.

Finally, the `img` event grabs the default `width` and `height`, assigns them to said variables (`d_w` and `d_h`), checks which side is longer, and with the help of `Paulo`, calculates the step for each percent based on the offset of the actual size vs the minimum. I tested this on Chrome, FF, and IE 10+ and it's working fine. It'll work on IE 9>, but you'll have to use `attachEvent` and no `range` element. Hope this helps.

**EDIT**
I put the `slider` event within the `img` load event to prevent premature firing of the code. I could tweak this more and even make it a stand-alone 'class' (well, kinda, JS classes are weird) if you like, let me know and I'd take a swing at it.